# is there a function that would remove all special characters from a formula field

Tags: formula-field

I want to remove all special characters from a formula field called "ABC". Is there a way I could use one function that could remove all special characters or do I need to specify each special character in the substitute function?

Thanls

Comment: Have you looked at the [`replace`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya, unfortunately you will have to do it for each one of them.
find and substitute functions should suffice your need.

Comment: Looks to me like it provides an answer. It says to use find and substitute functions. I'm not going to comment on the quality of the answer, but it does, in fact, provide an answer.

Comment: That is just an automated comment for review. The selection basically is meant to say "this content would be better posted as a comment".

Answer (score 0):

Within the Apex String Class, there is the replaceAll function: replaceAll(regExp, replacement) replaces each substring of a string that matches the regular expression regExp with the replacement sequence replacement.
Example:

```
String s1 = 'a b c 5 xyz';
String regExp = '[a-zA-Z]';
String replacement = '1';
String s2 = s1.replaceAll(regExp, replacement);
System.assertEquals('1 1 1 5 111', s2);
```

See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm

But I think in a formula field there is only "Substitute" available. You can build complex logic here as well, see https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5